# IOS: Add UIButton to the bottom of a Static Table View inside Container view and Navigation Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicontainerview

I have this problem:

I want to add a button to the bottom of a static table view controller. This all inside a Navigation Controller. I know that static table view can be used inside Navigation Controller only with a TableViewController. Ok no problem, I create a ViewController with a Container view connected to TableViewController. That's it. But now when i add the button outside container view, the button is shown in every controller. Is there a way to show only in the first view controller, without removing programmatically?

[image]

Comment: You either have to use different cell types, or use a regular viewController and place the button outside of the tableView.

Comment: This is why I tend to use a UIViewController, and add the UITableView to it.  Once you have added the delegates, you have the same functionality, but with more control to customise

Comment: How do you show the next view controller? If it's a 'push' in the navigation controller you should not see the button, but if it's a model presentation from the child (inner table view controller you might getting weird results).

Comment: Why don't you place the button in footerview?

Comment: The footerView is something you scroll to. What if you want the button to always show at the bottom of the screen.

Comment: But if I use a ViewController with TableView inside I cannot use NavigationController because I'm using static table view. I'm in loop

Comment: Yes, it's a push segue between TableViewController. The Button stuck in every windows.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
I had to put in storyboard another VIEW before pushing the Button. And in next tableViewController no button is shown.

[image]

Comment: Thank you) You save my time!